# how to make wordpress admin screen fields required

Tags: wordpress, field

I was wondering if it is possible to make fields in the admin area (for instance on the user page) required or optional.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have take reference URL https://www.cssigniter.com/how-to-add-a-custom-user-field-in-wordpress/

---

**Showing the user field**

---

As mentioned in the registration form, actions ‘show_user_profile‘ and ‘edit_user_profile‘ are available for adding our own user fields. The former fires when users are seeing/editing their own profile information, while the latter fires when a user (such as an admin) sees/edits another user’s profile. Both actions pass a WP_User object as their sole parameter. Our previous code, which already uses those actions, was this:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function crf_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {   ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Personal Information', 'crf' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="year_of_birth"><?php esc_html_e( 'Year of birth', 'crf' ); ?></label></th>
            <td><?php echo esc_html( get_the_author_meta( 'year_of_birth', $user->ID ) ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

Let’s go ahead and change the plain text year of birth, to an input element, so that it may accept user input.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function crf_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    $year = get_the_author_meta( 'year_of_birth', $user->ID );
    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Personal Information', 'crf' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="year_of_birth"><?php esc_html_e( 'Year of birth', 'crf' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="number"
                   min="1900"
                   max="2017"
                   step="1"
                   id="year_of_birth"
                   name="year_of_birth"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( $year ); ?>"
                   class="regular-text"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

Let’s check our profile page:

[image]

Comment: Thank's for the answer. However If I understand correctly this deals with adding a new field to the admin screen. My question is more about the existing fields like Firstname, Lastname and so on. I would like to know how to make these fields mandatoy.. Kind regards, Michel